# Simple VST Host doesn't open Plugin

Tags: c#, host, vst

I am trying to write a VST Host which basically should provide a better interface to control to Plugins at the same time. For that i looked searched for the best way to do it and stumbeld over VST.NET. Now i made this code to just simply open a plugin:

```
HostCmdStub cmdstub = new HostCmdStub();
VstPluginContext cont = VstPluginContext.Create("C:\\Program Files\\..\\Turnado.dll", cmdstub);
Logger(cont.PluginCommandStub.GetProductString());
cont.PluginCommandStub.Open();
```

(Code for the HostCmdStub taken from https://github.com/perivar/AudioVSTToolbox/blob/master/ProcessVSTPlugin/HostCommandStub.cs)
The Looger correctly logs Turnado so the dll seems to be loaded but nothing opens.
I don't really have any experience with VST.NET and my C# knowledge is also not that fresh. (If I could i would write the host in something like Java but there seems to be no good way to do so...also it seems not a good idea performance-wise).
Is there an obvious problem with my code or even a better way to create a host...I might even switch Programming language as i'm not that invested in the c#/VST.NET project yet.

Comment: The interaction between VST host and plugin is quite elaborate. I would suggest you examine the VST.NET Host sample (source code tab on the codeplex site) to get some idea what the patterns are.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I for some reason must have completely overlooked these samples. I had a quick look at the classes inside the Host sample and what do you know. All there was missing was:
            cont.PluginCommandStub.EditorOpen(form.Handle);